# Code printing unexpected results

Tags: java, math, printing, gravity

For some reason, Mercury and Venus print Infinity in the weight field. Can anyone see the problem? Does this code work for you guys? All the other planets seem to work fine. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Weight
{

    static double getGravity(String name) throws IOException
    {

        String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
        double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
        double[] masses = {3.3022 * Math.pow(10,23), 4.8685 * Math.pow(10,24), 5.9736 * Math.pow(10,24), 6.4185 * Math.pow(10,23), 1.8986 * Math.pow(10,27), 5.6846 * Math.pow(10,26), 8.6810 * Math.pow(10,25), 1.0243 * Math.pow(10,26), 1.312 * Math.pow(10,22)};
        int i = java.util.Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(name);

        return 6.67 * Math.pow(10, -11) * masses[i] / Math.pow(radii[i]*1000, 2);

    }

    static double convertWeight(double originalWeight, double currentGravity, double newGravity)
    {
        return originalWeight * (newGravity / currentGravity);
    }

    static void printResults(String name, double gravity, double weight)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-8.1f %-8.1f\r\n", name, gravity, weight);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        Scanner in;
        System.out.print("Enter your weight in lbs: ");
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double earthWeight = in.nextDouble();

        String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
        //PLUTO IS NOT A PLANET!

        double[] gravity = new double[names.length];
        double[] weight = new double[names.length];
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-8s %-8s\r\n============================================\r\n", "Planet", "Gravity", "Weight (lbs) ");
        for(int i=0; i<gravity.length; i++)
        {
            gravity[i] = getGravity(names[i]);
            weight[i] = convertWeight(earthWeight, gravity[2], gravity[i]);
            printResults(names[i], gravity[i], weight[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to read `gravity[2]` before you assign to it (which happens in the iteration where `i` is `2`). Java gives it the default value of `0`, and, in floating point, dividing by `0` gives `INF`.

Comment: A side-suggestion: define a Planet class that holds the planet name, radius, and mass or at the very least pass your lists to the get gravity method so you need not re-declare and initialize the same information repeatedly.

Comment: @synchronizer I would but this is for virtual school. I'm just doing an assignment.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

gravity[2] has to be set before looping or you divide by 0 until Earth.